# How do I get rid of extra todo states in my org agenda view?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

For some reason, when I pull up agenda view, I get a bunch of extra todo types, and I'm not sure where they came from.  When I pull up agenda view, I get this at top

[image: too many todo types]

The offending file seems to be my oldest org files called `notes.org`.  When `notes.org` is included in my `org-agenda-files` variable I get this long list of todo types, some of which I had added to my todo types previously, long ago, but have since deleted (like PROJ and HOLD) and others that are very weird and mysterious (like (8)[ ] and (9)[-]).

To try and narrow it down, I made a copy of `notes.org` called `trashnotes.org` and added `trashnotes.org` to my `org-agenda-files` variable, and then one by one deleted each top level heading I had in there, and refreshed my org agenda view checking to see if any of the headings had an offending line that would cause all of these extra heading types, but confusingly enough, even after I deleted *everything* in `trashnotes.org` the org agenda view *still* had the extra heading types.

Not only that, but if I took `trashnotes.org` out of my `org-agenda-files` variable then delete the `trashnotes.org` file, then make a new completely empty `trashnotes.org` file (`touch trashnotes.org`) and then add `trashnotes.org` back to my `org-agenda-files` variable, the extra todo types come back!

When I have `org-agenda-files` variable set only to my `todo.org` file (which is much smaller than my `notes.org` file) I only have the appropriate todo types in my org agenda view.

Also, I set my org agenda types by adding a line like `#+TODO: TODO PROJECT NEXT-ACTION WAITING | DONE CANCELED` to each `.org` file.

I have no idea what's going on... any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: If all of them are supposed to have the exact same set of workflow states, then it is simpler to define `org-todo-keywords` appropriately and get rid of the `#TODO: ...` lines in each file. In fact, you might want to look at the value of that variable, in both the "good" and "bad" cases and see if/how they differ. You might also want to update your question with that information.

Comment: So this got me well on my way to mostly fixing it.  I found out that I not only have `org-todo-keywords` but I also have a variable `org-todo-keywords-1` and I have no idea how or when I made that.  I've gone from spacemacs, to vanilla, to DOOM emacs and I always cleared my `.emacs` directory, maybe it snuck in? Using variable help I found that it is referenced in `~/.config/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build/org-plus-contrib/org-pcomplete.el` and `~/.config/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build/org-plus-contrib/org.el` and `~/.config/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build/org-plus-contrib/org-agenda.el`

Comment: Please don't do anything to `org-todo-keywords-1`: I believe it's an internal variable that is not supposed to be changed by users.

Comment: But that was the variable that was causing all the problems.  That was the variable that was set with all the strange `TODO` headings.  Now that I'm using [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda) I get doubles of every `TODO` in the list, and I believe it's because I have _two_ variables `org-todo-keywords` and `org-todo-keywords-1`.  If I could somehow _get rid_ of `org-todo-keywords-1` I think all my problems would be solved.

Comment: I don't think so: as I said, org-todo-keywords-1 is set internally to be the set ot TODO/DONE keywords active in a buffer. You cannot get *rid* of it without breaking org mode: what you can do is find out how it is modified and then figure out what *external* variables affect it and go after them.